# Is there a Windows API for converting File ID and Volume Serial to a unique path?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Background: I know that in Windows, two volumes with the same serial cannot be mounted at the same time. Moreover, there cannot exist two files within a single mounted volume with the same file ID. EDIT: this may not be the case. Then, given any volume handle or drive letter, the file_id maps to a unique file path. Is there a Windows API that can do this for any volume?

Progress: Here's how far I got:

```
#import <Windows.h>
...
    FILE_ID_DESCRIPTOR file_id;
    file_id.dwSize = 24;
    file_id.Type = FileIdType;
    file_id.QuadPart = /* file reference number */;
...
BOOL File::open(HANDLE *volume) {
    file = OpenFileById(*volume, &file_id, SYNCHRONIZE | FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES
                        | READ_CONTROL | ACCESS_SYSTEM_SECURITY,
                        SHARE_MODE, NULL, OPEN_FLAGS);
    if (file == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        if (GetLastError() == 1314UL) { /* SACL permissions denied */
            file = OpenFileById(*volume, &file_id, SYNCHRONIZE | FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES
                                | READ_CONTROL, SHARE_MODE, NULL, OPEN_FLAGS);
            perms = 0x4 | 0x2 | 0x1;
        }
        if (GetLastError() == 5UL) { /* Security permissions denied */
            file = OpenFileById(*volume, &file_id, SYNCHRONIZE | FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES,
                                SHARE_MODE, NULL, OPEN_FLAGS);
            perms = 0x2 | 0x1;
        }
        if (file == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) { /* All permissions denied */
            file = OpenFileById(*volume, &file_id, SYNCHRONIZE,
                                SHARE_MODE, NULL, OPEN_FLAGS);
            perms = 0x1;
        }
        if (file == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) /* File name denied|file doesn't exist */
            perms = 0;
    } else {
        perms = 0x8 | 0x4 | 0x2 | 0x1;
    }
    return file != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
}
...
    if (perms) {
        path = new WCHAR[260]; /* expected file length */
        l = GetFinalPathNameByHandle(file, path, 260, 0);
        if (l >= 260) {
            delete[] path;
            path = new WCHAR[l];
            GetFinalPathNameByHandle(file, path, l, 0);
        } else if (l <= 0) {
            delete[] path;
            path = NULL;
        }
    }
```

In the first part of the code, I open a handle to the file, using an already-open handle to the volume, which is easy to do given the mounted drive letter. `file` is a handle to the file I am about to open. 
In the second part, I use the handle to acquire the full name including DOS-style drive name (for example, `C:\Users\rmanne\Downloads\test.txt`). As long as `perms` is non-zero, I am guaranteed a human-readable absolute path in the second part of the code. However, I have only tested this with NTFS. According to the API, it will work with CsvFS and ReFS as well, but I haven't had a chance to test it with these yet.

The two functions are provided here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364962%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365432%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

As you can see, `GetFinalPathNameByHandle` is well-defined for all filesystems that Windows can mount and read without extra drivers or work-arounds. However, `OpenFileByFileId` is only defined for NTFS, ReFS, and CsvFS. I do not know whether or not it is defined for FAT or exFAT drives. However, it will, by specification, not work with network shared drives (SMB).

I have the option to just cache the file name because of the way I traverse all of the files, but caching these is incredibly memory-inefficient, taking up to 500MB of memory, whereas, not caching takes about 100MB of memory. Is there a different api that would enable me to get the name of a file given the  file_id?

Comment: @Andrew, Is that better good sir?

Comment: Where did you get the idea that "two volumes with the same serial cannot be mounted at the same time"? I just tried it, and Windows has absolutely no complaint about mounting multiple NTFS volumes with identical Volume Serial Numbers.

Comment: If you want it to work with file systems that don't support unique file IDs then I don't think you have any choice. Only the full path + filename of a file is guaranteed to be unique.

Comment: @AndrewMedico Hmm, I remember trying to mount multiple drives with the same serial before (two of the same drives). One of the mount points was already loaded to the RAM. I tried to mount the other was mounted by the Windows native disk mounter, but it said that the volumes conflicted. Well, if that isn't the case, at the very least, given an arbitrary volume handle, files have unique file reference numbers.

Comment: I believe it is the disk signature, rather than the volume serial number, that must be unique.  AFAIK, FAT doesn't have file IDs, and SMB probably doesn't expose them for security reasons.

Comment: Can you summarize what you're trying to achieve? What does a 'unique path' mean? Do you mean you can mount a drive at E:\, unmount it, and remount it at G:\ and get the same path identifiers? Do you want to track files that have been relocated/renamed?

Comment: @HarryJohnston yep, you're right about the signature. Are you certain that FAT doesn't have file IDs though? If that were the case, how would: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh447298(v=vs.85).aspx, format file index on a FAT volume?

Comment: @CollinDauphinee not quite, I can do that already by getting the volume serial (though I should probably start getting signature instead) and then changing the drive letter to match. By 'unique path', I'm trying to find the path that the file reference number maps to, without having to store the path string in memory until I write it to file.

Comment: I'm fairly sure.  FAT is [described on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_of_the_FAT_file_system) and I see no mention of anything resembling a file ID.  Files are identified by their cluster number, i.e., their actual location on the disk, and of course this may change as a result of defragmentation.  The file index is relative to the directory entry, it isn't unique for the volume, and even given a handle to the directory I don't see any way to use it to open the file.

Comment: You're out of luck if you want to support all file systems. You're basically looking for a database, so I would suggest using a key/value store that pages to disk or sqlite.

Comment: Also be aware that file IDs are reused.  So when you open a file by ID, you might be getting the original file, or the original file might have been deleted and you've opened one that was created since then.

Comment: Of course, the second case is OK. But I just dislike having to cache the names in memory. I'll probably try to just store them on a disk instead. Or just not store the whole name and instead just store its name and the ID of its parent, which should decrease memory usage, but should also be on orders of magnitude slower.

I didn't realize FAT had these weird perks.